# Searching for a phrase in hard-wrapped text

Tags: search

When searching for a phrase in hard-wrapped text, one wants newlines to be treated as spaces.  Can one have that happen?  Saying `/the\_sphrase\_sI\_sseek` is a bit awkward.

Comment: See this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11848 for a custom function (and command) that does what you want. Adjust to your taste.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it can't make use of incremental search.  But `cmap <m-space> \_s\+` works well (in nvim).

Comment: Whatever floats your boat is ok :)

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically replace a space with `\_s` when searching with:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Space> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ? '\_s' : ' '
```

Because `cnoremap` is applied to all the commandline (and not just search), we need an expression mapping to check if we're searching or in another commandline mode (e.g. `:`).

---

Because you probably don't *always* want to search like this, you can trigger this newline-insensitive mode with something like:

```
fun! StartNewlineSearch()
    cnoremap <expr> <Space> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ? '\_s' : ' '

    " Unmap both <Space> and this same mapping when pressing <CR>
    cnoremap <CR> <CR>:cunmap <lt>Space><CR>:cunmap <lt>CR><CR>:cunmap <lt>Esc><CR>

    " And the same for <Esc>
    cnoremap <Esc> <Esc>:cunmap <lt>Space><CR>:cunmap <lt>CR><CR>:cunmap <lt>Esc><CR>
endfun

nnoremap // :call StartNewlineSearch()<CR>/
```

When pressing `//` it maps `<Space>` to `\_s`, and it unmaps it when pressing `<CR>` or `<Esc>`.

---

You could also map this to a key to toggle the two "modes":

```
let g:search_mode = 0
fun! ToggleMode()
    if g:search_mode == 0
        cnoremap <expr> <Space> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ? '\_s' : ' '
        let g:search_mode = 1
    else
        cunmap <Space>
        let g:search_mode = 0
    endif
    return getcmdline()
endfun

cnoremap <C-@> <C-\>eToggleMode()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The other answser](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9379/6498) is certainly great.

However, I've found that it has one weakpoint, which is not necessarily negligible: if you abort the special search, i.e. you press <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>(changed your mind)<kbd>Escape</kbd>, you'll get `E385: Search hit BOTTOM without match for:`    ; afterwards you'll get the same error even for plain <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>, which is a bit annoying.

Probably the fix is easy, but I wanted to explore other ways of solving the same problem, so I came up with another solution:

```
fun! EnableAutocmdToUnmapSpace()
  augroup UnmapSpaceAug
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdLineLeave,CmdWinEnter / cunmap <space>
    autocmd CmdLineLeave,CmdWinEnter \? cunmap <space>
  augroup END
endf
fun! s:ctrlSMakesSpaceEOLFriendly()
  augroup UnmapSpaceAug
    autocmd!
  augroup END
  cnoremap <expr> <silent> <C-S> execute(':cnoremap <lt>space> \_s\+\| call EnableAutocmdToUnmapSpace()')
endf
augroup EOLFriendlySpace
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdLineEnter,CmdWinLeave / execute(':call s:ctrlSMakesSpaceEOLFriendly()')
  autocmd CmdLineEnter,CmdWinLeave \? execute(':call s:ctrlSMakesSpaceEOLFriendly()')
  autocmd CmdLineLeave,CmdWinEnter / cunmap <C-S>
  autocmd CmdLineLeave,CmdWinEnter \? cunmap <C-S>
augroup END
```

It is slighly longer, but it doesn't suffer the issue I described above. And it works differently:

- when you start your search with <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> behaves normally,
- but if you hit <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>, then

  1. <kbd>Space</kbd> is `cnoremap`ped to `\_s\+`,
  2. and an `autocmd` is activated to `cunmap` it;
- quite importantly, before mapping <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>, we first clear the `autocmd` of point 2 above, because we don't want to `cunmap <space>` on subsequent searches where we don't hit <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>.
- leaving the search `cunmap`s <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>.
- `CmdWinEnter` is treated as `CmdLineLeave` and `CmdWinLeave` as `CmdLineEnter`, for the reason explained [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39878/is-it-correct-that-between-a-cmdlineleave-and-a-cmdwinenter-there-must-be-a-cmdl); it is fundamentally depending on an implementation detail, but that's necessary to deal with the case that you hit <kbd>/</kbd> from within the command window, e.g. if you do <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> from normal mode.
- To make things work for <kbd>?</kbd>, the `autocmd` needs that you write `\?`, not `?`, as explained [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11856).