# Why rhs of cnoremap (used as a rhs of another cnoremap) can be <c-s> but not <space>?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, escape

If you execute this

```
cnoremap <expr> <silent> <C-S> execute(':cnoremap <c-s> ctrl-s')
```

and then hit <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>, you'll see the search command be populated by `/ctrl-sctrl-sctrl-s`.

Good.

But what's special in `<space>` not to work like that?

After executing this

```
cnoremap <expr> <silent> <C-S> execute(':cnoremap <space> space')
```

as soon as I hit <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>, I get `E385: Search hit BOTTOM without match for: ^S`.

To get the thing to work, I have to alter the command above to look like this

```
cnoremap <expr> <silent> <C-S> execute(':cnoremap <lt>space> space')
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map command substitutes all "angle brackets" inside. Really **all** of them.

Therefore, the second map gets either ctrl-s as byte#19 (which is ok) or space as byte#32 (which is a literal space to eat). And then some cryptic errors appear for the second case only.

There could be different solutions but the most straightforward one is always to use `<lt>` instead of `<` inside nested maps. This way all nested expansions will be performed in two steps.

Comment: At which point does `':cnoremap <space> space'` become `':cnoremap   space'`? In the context of `cnoremap`? Or in the context of `execute`? Or what?

Comment: Well, from the first paragraph of your answer, I understand it happens as soon as the mapping is created.

Comment: Mmm. There's still something I don't understand. Paradoxically, it is maybe _why does `':cnoremap <c-s> ctrl-s'` work?_ I mean, I don't understand what _ctrl-s as byte#19 (which is ok)_ means.

Comment: @Enlico Exactly. **Every** map expands **everything** it can. Just imagine how would you program it in the most straightforward way: never check anything except "less-than" and "greater than".

Comment: @Enlico As I mentioned above, c-s is byte#19. And it is okay. That is, you can put "control codes" right inside vim source and they will work (well, sometimes in some specific places, of course).

Comment: FYI, I asked this in the process of giving [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38963/6498).