# Is it correct that between a CmdlineLeave and a CmdwinEnter there must be a CmdlineEnter?

Tags: autocmd, command-line-window, cmdline, events

Given

```
augroup Dummy
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdLineEnter / echom "CmdLineEnter /"
  autocmd CmdwinLeave  / echom "CmdwinLeave  /"
  autocmd CmdLineLeave / echom "CmdLineLeave /"
  autocmd CmdwinEnter  / echom "CmdwinEnter  /"
augroup END
```

I noticed that `:messages` shows

```
CmdLineEnter /
CmdwinEnter  /
CmdwinLeave  /
CmdLineLeave /
```

whether I enter and exit the command window directly (<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>) or from the command line (<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).

So I'm tempted to conclude that it's not possible to trigger a `CmdwinEnter` (resp. `CmdlineLeave`) right after `CmdlineLeave` (resp. `CmdwinEnter`) without triggering `CmdlineEnter` (resp. `CmdwinLeave`) first.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation detail and it is not documented anywhere. Hence, it is absolutely **NEITHER SAFE NOR RECOMMENDED** to rely on this behaviour.

But, yes, `q/` (and similar) is internally mapped to `/` followed by `Ctrl-F` (or whatever is `&cedit` option value). This is done in `src/normal.c` inside `nv_record()` function.